# Firebase auth internal error "SignUp are blocked" on web

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth for a site and chosen password authentication and Google Sign In. When I ran it I got the following:

`{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignUp are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignUp are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}`

I already enabled both password and Google Sign In from Firebase console and also enabled the Identity Toolkit API in my Google Cloud Platform console but I still get this error.

Comment: i have the same problem after i implement google map API and restrict the key. So i solved it by not restricting the key.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In my case the `apiKey` in the environment file of Angular was allowed to only use a few Google Cloud APIs as I had restricted.

1. I went to https://console.cloud.google.com, chose the project (same as the Firebase project of course) and then **API & Services** > **Credentials**.
2. There in the list of API keys I looked for the same `apiKey` given in the project overview of Firebase, clicked on it and went on the tab API restrictions.
3. There with the select box I added to the list of allowed APIs the **Identity Toolkit API**.

Comment: thanks for this useful Answer, helping me fix the issue :)

Comment: wow spent a day on that and finally saw this, i only realized after hitting the api route instead of firebase internal, the firebase ios/android client one gave no useful error message but rest api gave 403

Comment: Identity Toolkit API is the key. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

As directed by @Marco Maccio

I went to https://console.cloud.google.com,
chose the project

`(same as the Firebase project of course)`

and then API & Services > Credentials.
There in the list of API keys,

```
I looked for the same API key given in the project overview of Firebase,
```

clicked on it, and went on the tab API restrictions.
Therewith the select box, I added to the list of allowed APIs the Identity Toolkit API.

or make it Don't restrict key

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there is not a "API restrictions tab" in 2019, i'm really confused about this issue, looks like Identity Toolkit was deprecated :L

**UPDATE:**

I fond a solution, there is not a tab, is a section, I did publish my solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20545

Comment: This should be rather a comment.

Comment: I fond a solution, there is not a tab, is a section, I did publish my solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20545

Comment: stackoverflow says: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `apiKey` that doesn't forbid access to the `identitytoolkit`

Comment: How do I set that? Can you walk me through to get that done?