# Angular 8 Firebase Login with Google failing with previously working project

Tags: firebase, google-authentication

I am working with a previously working Angular 8 project.  The Auth module is not working as expected.  When you click "login with google" the google account picker window pops up but then dissapears immediately.

Basically 403: Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.ProjectConfigService.GetProjectConfig are blocked

In the debug window I get the following error chunk:

> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests to this API identitytoolkit
>   method
>   google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.ProjectConfigService.GetProjectConfig
>   are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests to this API
>   identitytoolkit method
>   google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.ProjectConfigService.GetProjectConfig
>   are
>   blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}

}

I have tried this on a couple of enviornements and it is still happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your `apiKey` has access to the `Identity Toolkit API`. The security policy configuration may have been updated.

See [Firebase auth internal error “SignUp are blocked” on web](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52970822/1164465)

Comment: That was it.  I had acted on an automated email months ago saying that my Firebase App was insecure because the key was too permissive.  I thought I had the right aspects allowed.  I guess not.  I set it back to no restrictions and now am able t log in.